# Get list of users who reacted to a specific message

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm learning discord.py and I'm trying to get the list of users (name/id) who reacted to a specific message.

Below is my code:

```
    async def ga(self, ctx):
        channel = ctx.channel
        users = ""
        async for message in channel.history(limit=200):
            if message.id == '613850569718890495':
                reactions = message.reactions
        async for user in reactions.users():
            users += user.name + ", "
        await ctx.send(content=f"user: {users}")
```

I don't get any error messages or any results either. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs are ints, not strings, and `Reaction.users` is an `AyncIterator` while `Message.reactions` is a regular list

```
channel_id = 12345  # Replace with channel id
message_id = 613850569718890495  # Note these are ints, not strings

@commands.command()
async def ga(self, ctx):
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
    users = set()
    for reaction in message.reactions:
        async for user in reaction.users():
            users.add(user)
    await ctx.send(f"users: {', '.join(user.name for user in users)}")
```