# Discord.py receives all reactions of a user in a channel

Tags: python, discord.py

Is it possible to get all the reactions of a user? So how many times he provided a message in the channel with a reaction and when (The messages are not from the bot itself)?

Example: I have a webhook (that comes every hour in a certain channel) and would like to know who all has reacted to it and when.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To get all the reactions to a message you can do what this person has answered in another question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57600030/16931004

You would have to change the message.id to every single message.id in the guild so you would have to read in the history of all messages and get their message.id and loop thru these with that bit of code

Then you would want to save information in a dictionary or list of everytime where your TARGET.USER is in the list of message.reactions

Sorry for putting this as an Answer... I can't comment on posts cause I have <50 rep